# Query based off one element

Tags: mysql, sql

I am given the following database schema

```
Cows (cowID, cowName, cowAge)
CowPurchaser (purchaserID, name, address)
PurchaseRecord (purchaserID, cowID, year)
```

For each year, the cow purchaser "FARMLAND" purchased atleast one cow, find the number of cows purchased. The output be set of tuples, which indicates the year and the number of cows purchased by "FARMLAND"

I am not sure how to approach this. I tried

```
SELECT (pr.year, COUNT(c.name))
FROM PurchaseRecord pr, CowPurchaser cp, Cows c
WHERE cp.name = "FARMLAND" AND COUNT(c.name) >= 1
```

This is not giving the result I want. What could I be doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: You need join conditions. Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Also, `GROUP BY` is needed.

Comment: Yes. As a rule, NEVER use archaic comma-join syntax.

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers (e.g. column names). Do you have a column called Farmland? If its a value (string literal), use single quotes, i.e. `'Farmland'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pr.year, COUNT(c.name)
FROM PurchaseRecord pr
     INNER JOIN CowPurchaser cp ON pr.purchaserID=cp.purchaserID
     INNER JOIN Cows c ON pr.cowID=c.cowID
WHERE cp.name = "FARMLAND" 
GROUP BY pr.year
HAVING COUNT(c.name) >= 1
```